# Listview Instance Subitems

Tags: vb.net, listview, oledbdatareader

I have a goal of populating a listview from the output data of a OleDb query. I can correctly populate the Item and one subitem with no issue. But I'm having trouble defining the other 4 subitems of each item.

As you know, typically you define subitems with

```
ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text = "Test Item 2"
```

But I can't figure out how to do that when working with an instance of a Listview which populates my Control Listview at runtime.

Here is the code I have, which sucessfully populates an item and one subitem:

```
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Dim com As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim reader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

    Try
        'Open the connection
        conn.Open()
        'Create a new instance of the command and provide the SELECT query, and the opened connection
        com = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Schedules", conn)
        reader = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        'Check to see if the SELECT query returned any rows
        If reader.HasRows Then
            'If so, perform a read for each row
            While reader.Read
                'Declare a new ListViewItem, and provide the information
                'to be shown in the very first column
                Dim item As New ListViewItem(reader.Item("colName").ToString)
                'Decare a new ListViewSubItem, and provide the information
                'to be shown in the second (and so forth) column
                Dim subItem As New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
                subItem.Text = reader.Item("colNextRun").ToString

                'Ideally, I'd like to add "colLastRun as another sub item
                'subItem1.Text = reader.Item("colLastRun").ToString

                'Add the ListViewSubItem to the ListViewItem
                item.SubItems.Add(subItem)
                'Add the ListViewItem to the ListView
                lv.Items.Add(item)
                'Repeat until all rows have been read
            End While
        End If
        'Close the reader
        reader.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        'If something went sideways, make sure that you close the connection
        'before exiting the method.
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations on figuring out a fix. You have done a very good job with your connection but connections need to be not only closed but disposed. Look into Using blocks which take care of both for you. They will close and dispose your database objects even if there is an error.

You don't need to create a subitems object for each subitem. The .Add method of the sub items collection can take a string which will provide the text for that subitem. Internally it will create the subitem and add it to the collection.

Note the use of `.BeginUpdate` and `.EndUpdate` on the ListView. If you are adding many items this will speed things up considerably. It prevents the control from repainting on each addition. It will repaint once when you finish adding all the items.

```
Private Sub FillListView()
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Schedules", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                ListView1.BeginUpdate()
                While reader.Read
                    Dim item As New ListViewItem(reader.Item("colName").ToString)
                    item.SubItems.Add(reader.Item("NextcolName").ToString)
                    item.SubItems.Add(reader.Item("NextcolName").ToString)
                    item.SubItems.Add(reader.Item("NextcolName").ToString)
                    ListView1.Items.Add(item)
                End While
                ListView1.EndUpdate()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got an idea after reviewing my own question I posted here. 
**I figured it out:**

You just have to define a second subitem.. DUH!

```
                'Decare a new ListViewSubItem, and provide the information
                'to be shown in the second (and so forth) column
                Dim subItem As New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
                Dim subItem1 As New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem()
                Dim subItem2 As New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
                subItem.Text = reader.Item("colNextRun").ToString
                subItem1.Text = reader.Item("colLastRun").ToString
                subItem2.Text = reader.Item("colFileLocation").ToString
                'Add the ListViewSubItem to the ListViewItem
                item.SubItems.Add(subItem)
                item.SubItems.Add(subItem1)
                item.SubItems.Add(subItem2)
```